# Kiel disting(ig)i du signifojn de "kiel"?

Tags: word-meaning

*Kiel* havas kelkajn signifojn. Estas malfacile distingi aŭ distingigi du el ili. Ekzemple:

> Kiel infano mi spertis feliĉajn jarojn.

"As a child" kaj "like a child" estas ĝustaj tradukaĵoj de *kiel infano*. Kiel oni povas (legante) distingi aŭ (parolante) distingigi tiujn du signifojn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vi povas uzi *samkiel* por la dua signifo:

> Samkiel infano mi spertis feliĉajn jarojn.

Tio estas, mi spertis feliĉajn jarojn tiel, kiel infano spertas feliĉajn jarojn.

La alian signifon vi povas esprimi per ekzemple *estante* aŭ *kiam mi estis*, aŭ io simila. Verŝajne la dua estas iom longa. PIV plue ofertas la partikulon [*estiel*](http://vortaro.net/#estiel). Mi ne povas fari iun (mal)rekomendon, ĉar mi fakte ne scias, kiom ĝi estas vere uzata. Mi ja rekonas la vorton, serĉinte ĝin, sed ne memoras vere vidi ĝin en reala uzo. [Laŭ ReVo](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/estiel.html#estiel.0) ĝi estas malofta kaj ĝi sugestas [*estkiel*](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kiel.html#kiel.est0).

---

Kiel legante distingi ilin, mi ne vere scias, krom de la kunteksto.

Comment: Iam mi legis ke la plej ebla kaŭzo de la malsukceso de la neologismoj estiel kaj estkiel estas ke oni povas same bone uzi la vorton “estante”: “Estante infano, mi spertis feliĉajn jarojn”. Mi do rekomendus “estante” kaj “samkiel” (aŭ “same kiel”)

Comment: `Kiam infano mi spertis feliĉajn jarojn.` por `estkiel` probable jam estas valida Esperanto. Kaj `kvazaŭ` eblas por `samkiel`; tamen `samkiel` estas solide bona.

Comment: @marcus Jes, tio havas sencon. Mia unua penso estis uzi _estante_ kaj poste memoris, ke estiel ekzistas.

Comment: @JoopEggen Mi ne vere konsentas kun via frazo, ĉar al via subfrazo _kiam infano_ mankas predikato. Ŝajnas, kvazaŭ vi nur havas unu ĉeffrazon kun du subjektoj. Mi pensas, ke _kvazaŭ_ nur funkcias anstataŭ _samkiel_, se temas pri nereala afero aŭ almenaŭ por emfazi tion.

Comment: @Joffysloffy [kiam por estkiel] en "kiel infano" `kiel` ja ankaŭ estas konjunkcio kun ellasata predikato "mi estis", Tre bona, ofta lingvouzo tio tamen ne estas. [kvazaŭ por samkiel] Uzo de Zamenhof: `la patro frapis sur la pordo, kvazaŭ li estus fremdulo`. Mi precize volis esprimi la nerealan sencon de `infano` en la dua ekzemplo. Mi esperas ke mi komprenis ke la dua kazo temas ne pri infano.

Comment: @JoopEggen Ke tio funkcias por unu korelativo ne implicas, ke ĝi funkcias por alia… Tia uzo de _kiel_ estas simple aparta signifo de _kiel_; estas neniu kialo, kial tio havus sencon por _kiam_. Mi ja interesiĝus, ĉu vi havus ekzemplon, kie tio estas uzata! Pri _kvazaŭ_ vi fakte ja tute pravas. Nun ke mi pensas pri tio… kutime _samkiel_ iel implicas, ke oni ne estas tia, kia estas tio, kio sekvas _samkiel_.

Comment: @Joffysloffy bone. Interese estas (ekz. por tradukisto) ke `samkiel` akcentas komunecon, kie `kvazaŭ` eble diferencon: "tiu fiula agas kvazaŭ generalo" - "nia heroo agas samkiel generalo".

Comment: @JoopEggen Aha, tio ja estas interesa. Tiun senton ankaŭ mi ja havas, legante tiujn du frazojn. Bonaj ekzemploj!

Comment: La esprimo _Kiam infano mi spertis feliĉajn jarojn_ ŝajnas tute bona por mi. En la vortaro de esperanto.es _kiam infano = infanaĝe_. Mi koncedas ke ĝi maloftas, sed ja aperas eĉ en Tekstaro: _Persono kiu konstante proviĝas kaj montriĝas senmanka, **kiam infano** kaj junulo kaj adolto, nepre devas fariĝi reganto kaj gardisto de la civito_.

Comment: @Vidamuzo Aha, interese. Dankon! Mi neniam vidis tian uzon de _kiam_, do por mi ĝi sonis stranga. Mi koncedas, ke ne nepras predikato en tiu gramatika strukturo.